# Calling method of template base class

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, clang

The following code compiles in visual studio 2015 (even with /Za option). It doesn't compile on gcc and clang.

```
struct A
{
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{
  void f()
  {
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct C : B<T>
{
  void f()
  {
  }

  void g()
  {
    B::f();
  }
};

int main()
{
  C<A> c;
  c.g();

  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://goo.gl/3ENi9h)

gcc - error: 'template struct B' used without template parameters
clang - error: 'B' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

Which compiler is compliant to standard specifications? Any ambiguity in the specs?

**Edit**
I've added `f()` in `C` to have a more pertinent example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally to call a base class function in this case you would write:

```
this->f();
```

If `f` and `g` were both static, you would of course not be able to do this, so instead you could write

```
B<T>::f();
```

This works because `B` is already in scope at the declaration of `C`, so the compiler already knows it's a template. If you do `B::f()` alone, the compiler will give you an error because it knows `B` is a template so it is supposed to have template arguments.

You might be wondering why you are allowed to omit the template arguments inside the definition of `B<T>` but not inside the definition of `C`. To understand this, you need to know that every class has an *injected-class-name* that behaves like a typedef declared at the very beginning of the class definition. So it is as though the definition of `B` started with

```
typedef B<T> B;
```

Using `B` inside the definition of `B<T>` will find the *injected-class-name*, not the template. But when you are inside `C`, this `B` is not visible since it is declared inside `B<T>`, which is a dependent base class, and dependent base class scopes are not searched during unqualified name lookup (and `B` is on the left of `::`, so the lookup of `B` is unqualified). This also works:

```
C::B::f();
```

In this case, the *injected-class-name* `C` is found, and it refers to the dependent type `C<T>`, so the lookup of `B` will search inside the dependent base class `B<T>` and find the desired *injected-class-name*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `struct C`, the function `f` from `B` is being called without the template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know the `B` you're referring to in `B::f();`, try changing it to `B<T>::f();`.

Comment: Right, I know that B<T>::f() works. Developing cross platform code, it is annoying that some code is compiling with one compiler and not with others. I would like to know what says the standard about it and if the three compilers can be aligned to give the same compilation result (successful or not)...