# C++ template changes name lookup order?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f() {
        std::cout << "1";
}

struct B { 
        void f() { std::cout << "2"; }
};

struct D : B { 
        void g() {
                f();
        }
};

int main() {
        D d;
        d.g();
}
```

It outputs "2" when compiled with my g++ 11.2.0, c++17 standard. But if I turn these structures into templates like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void f() {
        std::cout << "1";
}

template<typename>
struct B { 
        void f() { std::cout << "2"; }
};

template<typename T>
struct D : B<T> {
        void g() {
                f();
        }
};

int main() {
        D<int> d;
        d.g();
}
```

It outputs "1"! Why?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095149/calling-method-of-template-base-class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128796/why-can-i-call-base-template-class-method-from-derived-class

Comment: This has to do with the two-phase lookup in templates. Since the base class is dependent on the template parameter, `f` is assumed to be the global `f`. If you use `this->f()` or `B<T>::f()` it will call the member function from the base class.

Comment: ... or `D::B::f()`